# Was Spartacus related to Sparta? Was he a Spartan?

Tags: ancient-rome, sparta

Was Spartacus related to Sparta?
[Spartacus](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Spartacus-Roman-gladiator) [lived from 103 BC to 71 BC in Roman Republic](https://yandexwebcache.net/yandbtm?fmode=inject&tm=1711791124&tld=eu&lang=en&la=1711368448&text=spartacus%20spartan&url=https%3A//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartacus&l10n=en&mime=html&sign=581b543e5faa6bc1428bfe3e9e609d00&keyno=0), when [Sparta](https://www.history.com/topics/ancient-greece/sparta) [(900s BC - 192 BC) had already stopped existing](https://yandexwebcache.net/yandbtm?fmode=inject&tm=1711791008&tld=eu&lang=en&la=1711218432&text=sparta&url=https%3A//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparta&l10n=en&mime=html&sign=efc1642b1878de8048ecdb8971389913&keyno=0)? But was he named after Sparta?

[He was a Roman gladiator. He was also a Thracian.](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Spartacus-Roman-gladiator)
Was he a Spartan? A Spartan wasn't necessarily a gladiator, and a Thracian wasn't a Spartan, correct?

Comment: One of the few things one seems to agree apon about [Spartacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartacus) early life was the he was [Thracian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thracians) (area around the present day borders of Bulgaria, Greece and Türkiye), which is no where near Sparta. Just because the  name Spartacus in Latin means **from the city of Sparta** doesn't mean the named person actually came from there.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Was Francis Scott Key French? Was Georgia Engel Georgian? Is India Arie Indian? Were the Romanovs Roman?

Comment: Since gladiators who fought in the Thracan style syle often fought against gladiators who fought in the Spartan style, I have assumed that "Spartacus" is a variation of "Sparticus", meaning victor over Spanta or Spartans.